# Activity still display on Recent app when press home

Tags: android, android-activity

I write an application start an new Activity with:

```
(android:excludeFromRecents="true") added on Androidmanifest file
```

but when i added more Intent Flag:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

When Activity running it still displayed in recent app.
So how can i start activity with (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and it disappear on recent
Thanks !

Comment: Can you add the `Manifest` file?

Comment: did you try android:noHistory="true" on manifest?

Comment: @lulian 
I added on Manifest

Comment: Can you please check again? It looks it didn't worked